# vue managing form editing state, boilerplate code

Tags: forms, vue.js, crud

I have a decent number of forms in my app, in which the user can choose to edit, revert, or save changes to the object, which are eventually saved to the backend.

Very similar to this: (code found in another question)
https://jsfiddle.net/k5j6zj9t/22/

```
var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        isEditing: false,
        user: {
          firstName: 'John',
          lastName: 'Smith',
        }
      },
      mounted() {
        this.cachedUser = Object.assign({}, this.user);
      },
      methods: {
        save() {
          this.cachedUser = Object.assign({}, this.user);
          this.isEditing = false;
        },
        cancel() {
          this.user = Object.assign({}, this.cachedUser);
          this.isEditing = false;
        }
      }
    })
```

Since `v-model` binding immediately changes the underlying object, I have to first create a clone of the object. Also I need to save a data member whether the object is in editing state.
Multiply this code for more forms and fields, and I end up with too much data members and a lot of boilerplate code.

In server frameworks like django, a model is in 'temporary state' until it is saved, so I can edit like this

```
user.first_name = 'aa' # temporary object in memory
user.save() # saved to the db
```

My question, is there a model component/pattern for vue to handle this task better?
Something that will hold the model state - i.e `isEditing`, automatically clone the object for form editing, revert the changes, etc.
So I won't have to write such code for so many objects?

Comment: I would use [mixin](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) for that purpose. So you'll be able to write just 1 mixin and use it everywhere where you're have such forms.

Comment: @Brissy Can you elaborate? I'm searching for hours and didn't find a solution

Comment: Does [this](https://jsfiddle.net/g6zm1y9b/6/) solve your problem?

Comment: Not exactly, I have a vue instance which is bound to multiple forms

Comment: And why can't we move each form to it's own component and extend it with mixin?
I'm afraid because all your forms are different you can't unify it :(

Comment: I am willing to create a form component. but how can I pass an object to the form component, so it will handle cloning the object, and setting v models? This is how i thought it should be done, but I cant think of an implementation

Comment: There is simple form component for string-fields-only-objects [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g6zm1y9b/86/) , do you need something like this? Or do you want to inline edit objects without modals/popups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uses [Scoped Slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots) may meet your requirements.

**My solution**:

1. Create one component with one slot
2. Then this slot will bind **values** with `clonedValues` (if **closeMode** is false, `clondedValues = values`)
3. finally, in parent component, generate your template with the properties of scoped slot, then pass it to the slot.

**Like below demo:**

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  template: `
  <div>
    <div>
      <slot v-bind:values="clonedValues"></slot>
    </div>
    <p>
      <button @click="saveAction(clonedValues)">Save</button>
      <button @click="resetAction()">Reset</button>
    </p>
  </div>`,
  props: {
    'cloneMode': {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true
    },
    'values': {
      type: Object,
      default: () => { return new Object() }
    }, 
    'saveAction': {
      type: Function,
      default: function (newValues) {
        this.$emit('save', newValues)
      }
    }, 
    'resetAction': {
      type: Function,
      default: function () {
        this.syncValues(this.values)
      }
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      clonedValues: {}
    }
  },
  created: function () {
    this.syncValues(this.values)
  },
  watch: {
    values: {
      handler: function (newVal) {
        this.syncValues(newVal)
      },
      deep: true
    },
    cloneMode: function () {
      this.syncValues(this.values)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    syncValues: function (newVal) {
      this.clonedValues = this.cloneMode ? Object.assign({}, newVal) : newVal // if you'd like to support nested object, you have to deep clone
    }
  }
})

Vue.config.productionTip = false

app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    mode: true,
    labels: ['id', 'name'],
    childForm: {
      'id': 1,
      'name': 'test'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    saveForm: function (ev) {
      Object.keys(this.childForm).forEach((item) => {
        this.childForm[item] = ev[item]
      })
      // call backend to update the data
    },
    changeCurrentValue: function () {
      this.childForm.id += '#'
      this.childForm.name += '@'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p><button @click="mode=!mode">Mode: {{mode}}</button></p>
  <p>Current: {{childForm}}  --<button @click="changeCurrentValue()">Change Current</button></p>
  <child :values="childForm" @save="saveForm($event)" :clone-mode="mode">
    <template slot-scope="slotProps">
      <p>ID: <input v-model="slotProps.values['id']"/></p>
      <p>Name: <input v-model="slotProps.values['name']"/></p>
    </template>
  </child>
</div>
```

**Edit for OP requested:**

1. change default slot to named slot=**edit**, then create one slot=**view**
2. added data property=**editing**, if true, show 'Edit' slot, if false, show 'View' slot.
3. in parent component, design the template for slot=**view**.

**Like below demo:**

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  template: `
  <div>
    <div v-show="editing">
      <slot name="edit" v-bind:values="clonedValues"></slot>
      <button @click="saveForm(clonedValues)">Save</button>
      <button @click="resetAction()">Reset</button>
    </div>
    <div v-show="!editing">
      <slot name="view"></slot>
      <button @click="editing = true">Edit</button>
    </div>
  </div>`,
  props: {
    'values': {
      type: Object,
      default: () => { return new Object() }
    }, 
    'saveAction': {
      type: Function,
      default: function (newValues) {
        this.$emit('save', newValues)
      }
    }, 
    'resetAction': {
      type: Function,
      default: function () {
        this.syncValues(this.values)
      }
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      editing: false,
      clonedValues: {}
    }
  },
  created: function () {
    this.syncValues(this.values)
  },
  watch: {
    editing: function (newVal) {
      if(newVal) this.syncValues(this.values)
    },
    values: {
      handler: function (newVal) {
        if(this.editing) this.syncValues(newVal) //comment out this if don't want to sync latest props=values
      },
      deep:true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    syncValues: function (newVal) {
      this.clonedValues = Object.assign({}, newVal) // if you'd like to support nested object, you have to deep clone
    },
    saveForm: function (values) {
      this.saveAction(values)
      this.editing = false
    }
  }
})

Vue.config.productionTip = false

app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    childForm: {
      'id': 1,
      'name': 'test'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    saveForm: function (ev) {
      Object.keys(this.childForm).forEach((item) => {
        this.childForm[item] = ev[item]
      })
      // call backend to update the data
    },
    changeCurrentValue: function () {
      this.childForm.id += '#'
      this.childForm.name += '@'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>Current: {{childForm}}  --<button @click="changeCurrentValue()">Change Current</button></p>
  <child :values="childForm" @save="saveForm($event)">
    <template slot-scope="slotProps" slot="edit">
      <h3>---Edit---</h3>
      <p>ID: <input v-model="slotProps.values['id']"/></p>
      <p>Name: <input v-model="slotProps.values['name']"/></p>
    </template>
    <template slot="view">
      <h3>---View---</h3>
      <p>ID: <span>{{childForm['id']}}</span></p>
      <p>Name: <span>{{childForm['name']}}</span></p>
    </template>
  </child>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to have the slot-scope on the root component element (a `<form>`)? instead of on a wrapper div. Also, does sloted scopes are the only way for a component to export methods? And, I don't see the edit option here, I thought I would clone the object only on edit, not on init, is it possible to implements this in this component? Also I don't need the cloneMode, I always need to clone when editing

Comment: @user3599803 updated the answer (added data property=editing). for your first question, you means change the root element of child component from `div` to `form`?

Comment: I am going to change the root element to form, I mean whether it is possible to skip on the <template> element, which feels somewhat weird. So the slot scope will bind to the root element component (`<child>`). Even though this solution does the job, I'm thinking whether it could be implemented without a scoped slot, maybe with a mixin that does the clone and adds an edit boolean. I will appreciate any pointers here